# Can PHP Extensions be written using C#

Tags: c#, php, .net

Is it possible to create a PHP Extension using C#?

We have a need to connect PHP to in house libraries we have written in C#.NET 4.6 targeting Windows and would like to be as close as possible to PHP without needing to have a serivce we can call external to php, thus the idea of making an extension in house.

I've looked at a couple options:

1. Use PHP DOTNET extension to call C# assembly.

   - As far as I can tell this extension does not work with .NET 4+ and the C# code requires 4.6 sadly.
2. Write a PHP extension.

   - So far I have only seen examples for Windows using Win32 and C++, idealy it would be nice if the extension could be written in C#. I have thoughts on making a lib using the C# code we need, then utilizing that inside the Win32/C++ extension and trying that if I absolutly have to.
3. Call the C# code as an external service.

   - As a very last option this would be viable and I can see this being more flexible for other sources to use (i.e. PHP, Java, C#, etc)

It would be interesting to be able to write a PHP Extension using C# assuming this is possible. I can see how this may not be the "best" option if it is possible though.

Thanks for reading and advice!!!

Comment: FYI, it's possible to write a COM/Automation wrapper in C# that would be callable using PHP COM functions. Or a mixed mode C++ PHP-to-.NET bridge. Both approaches are Windows specific. You don't tell whether C# is targeting Windows .NET or not. If not, C# on *nix is a whole different beast.

Comment: I haven't used it, but in the .NET Foundation there is this project [Peachpie](https://www.peachpie.io/usecases), and the use cases say that it can be used both ways. Alse, they have a [YouTube](https://youtu.be/xnQTsdJhvtk) channel that show how it works

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev sorry, I had forgotten that .NET went open source and is not Windows only anymore. This would be for Windows currently.

I will check out both ideas, using Peachpie if possible and the wrapper/bridge ideas. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Coming off of @SevaAlekseyev idea I was able to get PHP to call C# using COM.

```
<?php
$object = new COM('ComClassExample.ComClassExample');
echo '1 and 1 added: ' . $object->AddTheseUp(1,1);
?>
```

Using the following site I was able to make a C# dll that exposed itself like a COM object. https://whoisburiedhere.wordpress.com/2011/07/12/creating-a-com-object-from-scratch-with-c/

And with a little tweak to the Post-build event I was able to get the new version to load for PHP (had to copy because PHP was getting an access denied message)

```
iisreset /stop
copy /Y "$(TargetPath)" C:\com\$(TargetFileName)
$(frameworkdir)\$(frameworkversion)\regasm.exe C:\com\$(TargetFileName) /codebase /tlb /nologo
iisreset /start
```

@JuanDelaCruz Peachpie looks like an interesting tool to keep in mind but it looks like it is meant to be compiled before deployment which wont work in our shop for the moment.

Thanks all!